# Status 500 on Simple PHP Connection to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I'm running a fairly simple script on my server. I'm confident the server environment is stable because PHP scrips will `POST`, `ECHO`, successfully execute `phpinfo()`, etc.

The script that I am running in an attempt to connect to my MS SQL Server is as follows:

```
<?php
$serverName = "sql.xxx.com";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxData", "UID"=>"onlinexxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx");
echo "before server";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
echo "after server";

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

What prints to the screen is

> before server

but "after server" won't print, so I believe it's getting hung up on the

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

statement. Chrome console gives me a **Status 500** with an **Initiator: other** which makes troubleshooting tough.

Do I need to install a MS SQL plug-in DLL to my PHP extension for `sqlsrv_connect`? I've seen some MS forums where people say you do; others say you don't.

Comment: 500 is a server error; check your logs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, I'll check that.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I'm not using MySQL :]

Comment: Either the connection information is wrong or you dont have the SQL Server connector activated in PHP or you didnt install the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx)